# Separate "subequations" environment but same horizontal alignment

Tags: align, subequations

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a_1 x + b_1 &\geq 0 \\
a_2 x + b_2 &\geq 0 \\
a_3 x + b_3 &\geq 0
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\begin{align}
\therefore x \leq 0
\end{align}
```

This code produces the following:

[image: TeX example of a 'subequations' environment and two 'align' environments]

The numbering is what I desired, however, these expressions are not aligned horizontally with `&` since the code splits the `align` environment into three. Due to the split, in addition, the spaces between the lines (1c) and (2), and the lines (2) and (3), are larger than others.

If I set the equation number (2a) rather than (2), these two problems can be solved with the method in [Aligning consecutive align environments and keep equation numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381207/aligning-consecutive-align-environments-and-keep-equation-numbering) , but can the situation above be solved? I tried writing some codes but could not solve it.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Answer (score 2):

This works, but you should rethink whether you're really wanting it.

The `\renewcommand` should be adjusted if your equation numbers have more structure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\resetparent}[1][0]{%
  \stepcounter{parentequation}%
  \setcounter{equation}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}%
\renewcommand{\theparentequation}{\arabic{parentequation}}%
\begin{align}
a_1 x + b_1 &\geq 0 \\
a_2 x + b_2 &\geq 0 \\
a_3 x + b_3 &\geq 0 \\
\resetparent[-1]
\therefore x &\leq 0 \\
\resetparent
aaaa_1 x + b_1 &\geq 0 \\
a_2 x + b_2 &\geq 0 \\
a_3 x + b_3 &\geq 0
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]