# How to keep alignment across multiple align environments?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
w &z &t
\end{align}
\begin{align}
w+w+w+w &z+z+z+z &t+t+t+t
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

On their own, these are going to have differently aligned columns. Is there a way to keep at least some of the alignment across different align environments the same?

Comment: You can use `\intertext{<text>}` to interrupt an `align` environment. Is this what you want or do you want to align equations that are very far apart?

Comment: I have already used for some text, but I want different align environments for completely different text sections, though I want the equation alignment to remain consistent.

Comment: @user14554: So you have a "big piece of text" between the two `align`ments?

Comment: I have two large and distinct text sections with their own titles and such yes. I do not want them altered and intertext will not solve anything. As far as I know there is possibly some way to use fleqn.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to use fleqn and subequations, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: I think this is the right track https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381207/aligning-consecutive-align-environments-and-keep-equation-numbering
because I don't want to get rid of the align environments at all. The problem are it doesn't appear to change much except the labeling. It does keep the alignment across *consecutive* align environments, but then if the columns switch, from that point on, following align environments then follow that new alignment instead of the original.

Answer (score 3):

If you're unable to use `\intertext`, you need to identify the widest element around each alignment. And the easiest way to capture these "widest elements" is using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox). Below I define `\eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` that puts its contents `<stuff>` in a box of widest width across all of the same `<tag>` with a specific `<align>`ment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox,xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{align}
  \eqmathbox[left][r]{w} &\eqmathbox[centre][l]{z} & \eqmathbox[right][r]{t}
\end{align}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
  \eqmathbox[left][r]{w+w+w+w} & \eqmathbox[centre][l]{z+z+z+z} & \eqmathbox[right][l]{t+t+t+t}
\end{align}
\lipsum*[3]

\end{document}
```

The alignment choice matches that of the R`&`L `&` R`&`L ... style of `align`.

Since `eqparbox` uses TeX's `\label`-`\ref`-like system in order to manage the lengths, you'll need to compile at least twice with every change in the widest element per `<tag>`.